# Count duration between two times after midnight

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How to count duration between two times?

```
var start = moment('17:00', "HH:mm");
var end = moment('02:15', "HH:mm");
moment.duration(end.diff(start)).asHours()
//outputs  -14.75 instead of 9.15
```

Comment: I think the problem is that you have 2 moment objects, one representing today 17:00 and one today 02:15. Though you want today 17:00 and tomorrow 02:15. Just use `moment('02:15', "HH:mm").add(1, 'days')` to get the next day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

moment constructor defaults to current year, month and day, so your problem is that `end` is before `start`. You can compare your variables using [`isBefore`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/) and then use [`add`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) to "trasform" `end` to the next day.

Note that [`asHours`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/hours/) gives fractional values (so you'll have 9.25 instead of 9.15). If you need to get "9 hours and 15 minutes" you can use [moment-duration-format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/duration-format/) plug-in (for example you caun use `'h[.]m'` as [template](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format#template) in the [`format`](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format#basics) method).

Here a working sample:

```js
var start = moment('17:00', "HH:mm");
var end = moment('02:15', "HH:mm");
if( end.isBefore(start) ){
  end.add(1, 'day');
}
var dur = moment.duration(end.diff(start))
var result = dur.asHours();
document.writeln(result);
document.write(dur.format('h[.]m'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/1.3.0/moment-duration-format.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the simpliest way to count difference in one day:

```
var start = moment('17:00', "HH:mm");
var end = moment('02:15', "HH:mm");
var duration = moment.duration(end.diff(start)).asHours();
if (duration < 0) duration += 24;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you have 2 moment objects, one representing today 17:00 and one today 02:15. Though you want today 17:00 and tomorrow 02:15. Just use `moment('02:15', "HH:mm").add(1, 'days')` to get the next day.

```js
var start = moment('17:00', "HH:mm");
var end = moment('02:15', "HH:mm").add(1, "days");
var result = moment.duration(end.diff(start)).asHours();
document.write(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: this code was not correct if start time was less than end.
`var start = '02:15', end = '17:00';`

Comment: True, though the question doesn't really specify much. 
You could use Math.abs, or check which is earliest.