# Moment/JavaScript - Generate an array of time slots with a 15min cliff

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am generating the following array :

**Current output:**

```
["11:00", "11:15", "11:30", "11:45", "12:00", "12:15", "12:30", "12:45", "13:00", "13:15", "13:30", "13:45", "14:00", "14:15", "14:30", "14:45", "15:00", "15:15", "15:30", "15:45", "16:00", "16:15", "16:30", "16:45", "17:00", "17:15", "17:30", "17:45", "18:00", "18:15", "18:30", "18:45", "19:00", "19:15", "19:30", "19:45", "20:00", "20:15", "20:30", "20:45", "21:00", "21:15", "21:30", "21:45", "22:00", "22:15", "22:30", "22:45", "23:00", "23:15", "23:30", "23:45"]
```

**The code :**

```
var startTime = moment().utc().set({hour:11,minute:00});
var endTime = moment().utc().set({hour:23,minute:59});

 var timeStops = [];

while(startTime <= endTime){
    timeStops.push(new moment(startTime).format('HH:mm'));
    startTime.add(15, 'minutes');
}

console.log('timeStops ', timeStops)
```

**The problem :**

Currently, everything works fine and as expected; however, I have a kind of logical issue.

Let's suppose that the **endtime** is 2:00 am 2 hours after midnight, knowing that I am following the 24hours representation (as this is what required).

In this case it doesn't push anything on the array as it thinks that the endtime is before the start time; however, it's the endtime of the next day.

By the way, from the backend I receive the following :

```
 [11:00, 02:00] meaning [openingTime, closingTime]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply check if `endTime` is before `startTime` using [`isBefore`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/), then you can [`add`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) one day to make `endTime` represent the next day.

Here a live sample:

```js
function getTimeStops(start, end){
  var startTime = moment(start, 'HH:mm');
  var endTime = moment(end, 'HH:mm');
  
  if( endTime.isBefore(startTime) ){
    endTime.add(1, 'day');
  }

  var timeStops = [];

  while(startTime <= endTime){
    timeStops.push(new moment(startTime).format('HH:mm'));
    startTime.add(15, 'minutes');
  }
  return timeStops;
}

var timeStops = getTimeStops('11:00', '02:00');
console.log('timeStops ', timeStops);
timeStops = getTimeStops('11:00', '23:59');
console.log('timeStops ', timeStops);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42784265/4131048) a similar issue, with a similar solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would add date into the equation.

If you know you are going to go to 2am, then add the date to push it to the next day. You don't even necessarily need it to be the correct date, just one day in the future from start:

```
var startTime = moment().utc().set({day: 1, hour:11, minute:00});
var endTime = moment().utc().set({day: 2, hour:2, minute:59});
```

This should allow you to properly go from some time the previous day to an end time the next day.

Comment: That should work fine, however what I didn't mention is that I receive from the backend an array like the following `[11:30, 02:00]` meaning `[openingTime, closingTime]` how would I know in this case if day 1 or 2 ?

Comment: You can just add a simple check `time[1] < time[2] ? 2 : 1`. If your closing time is smaller than your start, then you'll know you've rolled to the next day.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [moment-range](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-range#by) iteration by (hours, minutes ....).

example:

```js
const range = moment.range('2018-01-01 00:00', '2018-01-01 05:30');
 
const hours = Array.from(range.by('hour', { excludeEnd: true }));
hours.length == 5 // true
hours.map(m => m.format('HH:mm')) // ['00:00', '01:00', '02:00', '03:00', '04:00']
```