# Compare only timepart in moment object

Tags: javascript, momentjs, date-comparison

I want to compare only the time part in a moment object. I have included a Snippet that at the moment does not work as intended. The filter function is not working properly. I want to filter out all dates that either has the start hour set before 07:00 or end hour set after 19:00. I Also get a deprecated warning that I can't really figure out the cause of. Thanks for all the help

```js
var arrayOfWorkDates = [{
  start: "2018-05-02T07:00:00Z",
  end: "2018-05-02T09:00:00Z"
}, {
  start: "2018-05-02T019:00:00Z",
  end: "2018-05-02T21:00:00Z"
}, {
  start: "2018-05-02T010:00:00Z",
  end: "2018-05-02T11:00:00Z"
}];

console.log(arrayOfWorkDates);

var StartHour = moment("07:00", "HH:mm");
var EndHour = moment("19:00", "HH:mm");

var filteredWokrHours = arrayOfWorkDates.filter(function(el) {

  return moment(el.start).isBefore(StartHour) || moment(el.end).isAfter(EndHour);
});

if(filteredWokrHours.length > 0){console.log("success: " + filteredWokrHours.length);}else{console.log("fail");}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42784265/4131048), I think that accepted answer can help you.

Comment: I found that post earlier and tried to apply that solution to my problem. but I ended up where I am now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it like this.

```js
var format = "HH:mm:ss";
var hourFormat = "HH:mm";
var maxStartHour = moment("07:00:00", format);
var minEndHour = moment("19:00:00", format);

var arrayOfWorkDates = [

  {
    start: "2018-02-24T14:00:00",
    end: "2018-02-24T15:00:00"
  },
  {
    start: "2018-02-24T05:00:00",
    end: "2018-02-24T06:00:00"
  },
  {
    start: "2018-02-24T20:00:00",
    end: "2018-02-24T21:00:00"
  }
];


var filteredWokrHours = arrayOfWorkDates.filter(function(el) {

  var start = moment(el.start).format(hourFormat);
  var end = moment(el.end).format(hourFormat);

  var checkHourStart = moment(start, format);
  var checkHourEnd = moment(end, format);

  return checkHourStart.isBefore(maxStartHour) || checkHourEnd.isAfter(minEndHour);
});

if(filteredWokrHours.length > 0){console.log("success: " + filteredWokrHours.length);}else{console.log("fail");}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```